# How to use JS innerHTML by class name and child of a class

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do a
document.getElementBy ***Class*** ("post[1] .classname").innerHTML ?

post[1] to be the second DIV with class='post' and I want the child .classname of this.

For example: I want to get the innerHTML of the second post => div class="inside".

```
<div class="post">Post 1
<div class="inside"></div>
</div>

<div class="post">Post 2
<div class="inside">//this here</div>
</div>

<div class="post">Post 3
<div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what jQuery was invented for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But if you don't want to use jQuery, but are OK with only supporting later browsers, you can use document.querySelector. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/4hEwd/

```
document.querySelector('.post:nth-child(2) .inside').innerHTML
```

Here's a list of browsers that support it: http://caniuse.com/queryselector

Comment: Wow that's great thanks man. Yes I was actually looking for a non-jquery version, though I might use jquery eventually now. Thanks for the fiddle!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

```
alert($('.post:nth-child(2) > div').html());
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AEeH6/).